# commandButton for removing images from p:galleria

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.0.2 with Glassfish 4 (Mojarra 2.2.0).

I've been trying to add a command button to delete/remove the selected image in a p:galleria component. I tried adding a button within the galleria component like this:

```
<p:galleria id="images" value="#{someBean.images}" var="image">
    <p:graphicImage value="#{image}"/>
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Delete #{image}" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; z-index:10;" 
        actionListener="#{someBean.deleteImage(image)}"
        update="growl images" />
</p:galleria>
```

I can display the image path fine within the button, but passing the image parameter in the EL Expression `#{someBean.deleteImage(image)}` does not work as expected.

The issue I have is that when `deleteImage` is called the image parameter (`String`) is always empty instead of containing the image name. However, `title="Delete #{image}"` displays fine, so I suspect `image` isn't resolved correctly within the `actionListener` or `action` attributes.

If I enter a literal string in the xhtml, e.g. `#{someBean.deleteImage('deleteme')}` it is passed correctly. Passing `null` also gives an empty string.

`someBean.images` is a `List<String>` (image paths).

I am at a loss :/ could anyone point me in the right direction? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I have also thought about adding a button outside the galleria component, but I am unclear as to how to determine the selected image without having to modify the p:galleria component. 
There is also an unanswered question about this (1yr old) [How to get the selected image from <p:galleria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948731/how-to-get-the-selected-image-from-pgalleria)

**Update:**
Appending `"test"` to `image` using `ui:param` or `c:set` will actually give me the string `"test"` within the `deleteImage` method, but the `h:outputText` component correctly renders the value of `image` with `"test"` appended. This suggests to me that they are rendered at different times - and the commandButton is rendered at a time when `image` is null?

```
<p:galleria id="images" value="#{someBean.images}" var="image">
    <p:graphicImage value="#{image}"/>
    <ui:param name="img" value="#{image}test"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{img}"/>
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Delete #{image}" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; z-index:10;" 
        actionListener="#{someBean.deleteImage(img)}"/>
</p:galleria>
```

**Update 2**

This could be related to a similar issue in Primefaces Extensions - maybe it is a bug after all. http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=39992

I also started a thread in the PF forum: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=40055

Comment: Could you try this dirty little hack: `actionListener="#{someBean.deleteImage(image.concat(''))}"`?

Comment: Sadly this doesn't change anything. Even `image.concat('test')` gives me an empty string. What I forgot to mention in the original post though is that a literal string is passed correctly.

Comment: As you probably figured, my idea was to catch the value while it is available. Can you try maybe one more thing: `<c:set var="img" value="#{image}/>"` before `<p:commandButton>`, and `#{someBean.deleteImage(img)}` in action listener? Though, I don't expect this to work when first suggestion failed.

Comment: doesn't work either - interestingly `#{someBean.deleteImage(null)}` also gives me an empty string, so probably `image` resolves to `null` at the time the JS for the action listener is generated, and PF replaces null with an empty string.

Comment: An interesting observation I just made: `<c:set var="img" value="#{image}test"/>` and `actionListener="#{imageHelper.deleteImage(img)}"` will give me the string `"test"` within the method. But `<h:outputText value="#{img}"/>` correctly renders the image path with test appended to it. I am now thoroughly confused...

Comment: I added the code to my post. To me this suggests that `p:commandButton` is rendered at a time when image is null, and `h:outputText` when image is set. But that must mean `c:set` is processed more than once.

Comment: Very interesting problem, too bad I don't have a JSF project in front of me, to poke around some more :/

Comment: Also, don't use <c:set... instead prefer <ui:param name="buttonText" value="#{myBean.MyValue}" />... c:set is JSTL

Comment: @henriquedsg89 I forgot to mention that `ui:param` leads to the same result. I updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Can you try if `<ui:param name="img" value="${image}test"/>` makes any difference (`$` instead of `#`)?

Comment: same result with `<ui:param name="img" value="${image}test"/>`

Comment: I'm trying to implement the same functionality with PF 6.1.7, so the problem remains, disappointingly.

Comment: I've created this forum post: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=52974

Answer (score 3):

```
 <p:galleria id="photoGalleria"
                    panelHeight="400"
                    panelWidth="450"
                    widgetVar="photoGalleriaWidgetVar"
                    style="width: 100%;"
                    autoPlay="false"
                    value="#{partEditBean.selectedPart.partPictures}" var="img">
            <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="wf" style="text-align: center;">
                <p:commandButton id="delete_pic_button"
                                 update="@form"
                                 value="#{msg['part_view.delete']}" process="@this"
                                 actionListener="#{partImageEditBean.deleteListener}">
                    <f:param name="pic_id" value="#{img.picId}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:graphicImage styleClass="wf galleriaOver" value="#{img.picUrlPath}"
                            title="#{partEditBean.selectedPart.partTreeNode.partPathName}"
                            onclick="window.open('#{img.picUrlPath}','_blank');"/>
        </p:galleria>



FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("pic_id")
```